# syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting end-of-input )

Tags: ruby, sintaxe

Me deparei com esse erro de sintaxe:

> syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting end-of-input )

```
larguraDaLinha = 40
str = '--> text <--'
puts str.ljust  larguraDaLinha
puts str.center larguraDaLinha
puts str.rjust  larguraDaLinha
puts str.ljust (larguraDaLinha/2) + str.rjust (larguraDaLinha/2)
```

https://repl.it/KtDA/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta parênteses nas chamadas da funções. Procure manter o código organizado e dentro de um padrão, assim evita erros assim.

```
larguraDaLinha = 40
str = '--> text <--'
puts str.ljust(larguraDaLinha)
puts str.center(larguraDaLinha)
puts str.rjust(larguraDaLinha)
puts str.ljust(larguraDaLinha/2) + str.rjust(larguraDaLinha/2)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/aN3Oeu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rbvxvcfn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/SyntaxFunction.rb).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @shxrk veja o **[tour]** a melhor foram de dizer obrigado.